# SherlockActionBar crashes if exported

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I implemented sherlockactionbar in my project and it works great, but I don't know why when I export my project with eclipse into an apk to finally publish it it doesn't even open! If I run it from eclipse it works perfectly...

this is the log:

```
06-28 15:54:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(3707): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.app.Activity, int]
06-28 15:54:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(3707):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.a(Unknown Source)
06-28 15:54:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(3707):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source)
```

It crashes during the *setContentView(..)* method.

What's the difference between exporting and running (not in debug) from eclipse? Shouldn't they be the same code with different key?

EDIT:

Ok, i got to the point that the problem si the SherlockActivity, not the theme. if I remove the prefix sherlock it doesn't crash even if using the theme.sherlock.light while compiling eclipse must ruin the code somehow...

I repeat: if i run it in debug or simply with the run button inside eclipse EVERYTHING works fine.

Comment: you say "from eclipse it works" does that mean the simulator?  have you ran the code on a physical device through ddms and eclipse?  also dont forget the sdk that your running on the simulator could be different from the real device (meaning maybe thats why the outcome is different)

Comment: you mean the "emulator", not "simulator". they are two completely different words and ideas.

Comment: and there is no difference... are you testing it with the same exact device?

Comment: yes sorry, the emulator, to much ios lately

Comment: yes, same exact phisical device. i also tried it with different os (2.3.7 and 4.0.3), same result: the apk exported crashes, but if i run the code from eclipse it works..

Comment: I was trying to leave this alone in hopes alex would take over since he seems to know more, but its been a while so ill take a shot.  Back to my original question when you say "from eclipse it works" are you running it in the emulator when it works or you have your phone attached to your computer and it runs on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after many trials i solved it! Eclipse wasn't compiling it correctly because i had two support.v4 jar inside my project! i hadn't noticed it... when you got two identical jar it doesn't give you an error but it fails in compiling correctly, in fact after removing it the size of my apk increased quite a lot too.

Comment: I run into a problem that looks similar. I use Sherlock too. I only have one support library jar, and its within ActionBarSherlock... Any other hint on what you did to fix this ?

Comment: Try disabling ProGuard, that helped me.

Comment: i've had compiler/environment issues from referencing both action bar sherlock and view page indicator because they both reference support v4. I would expect the environment to complain if you had more than one ref to support v4. or it may be I'm having the same issue as you. how did you get down to just one ref to support v4 then?

Comment: I ended up with importing the code from actionbarsherlock and viewpagerindicator in my own application so to just have one...